# Total number of views on each SO answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Total number of profile views and total number of views on questions are available on SO. Will it be good to have view count on each answer?

Comment: [Check this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292035/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-breakdown-of-the-people-reached-stat) for a rough idea of the number of views per answer.

Comment: How exactly do you expect them to do this?

Comment: Some thought points, total number of views on answer is same as of question against which answer is written but people are not reading all answers and if reading not necessary doing thumb up or down. How you can know, your answer was worth useful and viewed by people ?  Answers of same page will have same view count even if they were not read by any one. Views on questions are available to person who created question not to people who are giving answer, same count can be displayed to them as well.

Comment: Maybe how many views of page since answer was posted?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can distinguish viewing a question from scrolling down on a page and viewing some/all/none of the answers.

SO probably keeps track of access to shared links, and those direct access that could be displayed, but they are not the same as a view count on each answer.