# How is impact calculated in the profile view

Tags: discussion, profile-page, people-reached

I came across this profile [alex555](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171811/alex555) (I took this one but this could have been any other one) which as an *estimated impact* of 91K. I've got an impact of 99K.

```
Profile comparison:             |   Alex555     | Me
-------------------------------------------------------------
nb Of post                      :   70          | 260
Sum of upvotes of 10 top posts  :   32 upvotes  | 109 upvotes
rep                             :   0.6k        | 4.5k
profile view                    :   77          | 600
```

I don't care which of us got the most people reached, what I want to understand is *how the estimated impact is calculated* and if it's pertinent or not.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here - it is explained here.

Comment: I always failed to check the central meta :/ Thanks @Oded

Comment: You can also check which of your posts has contributed the most, check [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292035/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-breakdown-of-the-people-reached-stat)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The impact value is an estimation of the number of people you helped with asking questions and posting answers. It is a sum of all the views on those questions plus the views on posts you answered provided your answers meet certain criteria.

The current formula counts answers only if you had a real impact on the question; not all answers are thus counted. See [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here), but for answers you need to meet the following criteria:

- Non-deleted AND
- Score > 0 AND
- Also meets one or more of the following criteria:

  - In the top 3 answers OR
  - Is the Accepted Answer OR
  - Score >=5 OR
  - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

Alex has asked questions that with age have garnered several 1000s of views per question, and their [highest-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-a-label-in-windows-forms/9885459#9885459) is a top-3 answer on a question with almost 60k views, which helps a great deal to get them to that 91k number.

Your reputation and profile view counts don't have any impact here. The number of posts helps only in that you have more posts for which the views count towards the total.

Comment: What if it is an accepted answer but with Score = 0? The condition "Score > 0" will fail, and it will not be counted for impact calculation. Sounds unfair to me.

Comment: @HappyCoder: that's how it works; your answer should have been helpful to more than just the OP. Using score to measure this is a rough estimate of how useful your answer was to others; if 10k people viewed the question but no-one upvoted the answer, how helpful was it really?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The OP can *both* accept and upvote becoming the only one person who decides the answer is count among those affecting your impact.

Comment: @Nikolas I’m not entirely certain what your point is. Is that a problem? The OP doesn’t generate the views. They also have just one vote per post, on questions with loads of views there are also more votes, and those votes by others far outweigh that single vote. If you write a good answer, it really doesn’t matter what the OP accepted or voted on, not when it comes to having the views counted as impact.