# Has the impact calculation changed?

Tags: support, people-reached

(Not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315383/did-the-impact-calculation-changed-recently), because my impact has *increased*.

Up until last week my Impact was around 50-55k and was increasing slowly. It took me 2 years to get to this point.

Just two days ago, it blew up to 119k, and today it is at 134k (picture attached):

[image]

Is this abnormal increase to be expected? Or did the calculation for impact change?

Comment: @AndrewLi In the dupe case, it's highly possible a deleted post or something of the sort led to the decrease... but I can't imagine what would cause an _increase_...

Comment: Perhaps one of your answers on an old question with a large amount of views recently reached a score of 5? See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293949/563532) for the calculation

Comment: @Rob no, that specific case doesn't explain it. The most views Coldspeed has on a 5, 6 or 7 score answer is ~550 - on this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332960/interweave-two-dataframes/45333079#45333079. However, it could be one which is below 5 but crossed the 20% threshold, or an answer was deleted for some reason (so it moved to top 3). Chances are, one highly viewed question they've answered has crossed one of those thresholds.

Comment: @Tim Your comment got me thinking... I've recently posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364674/python-numpy-how-to-count-the-number-of-true-elements-in-a-bool-array/45519545#45519545) answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that’s in the top 3 - and would boost by around 72k - exactly the increase you saw!

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your help. I've understood the problem and also how the impact calculation works better.

Comment: The funny thing is that a single upvote to [your +4 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129224/1983854) will give you an extra 1.4m. That is, one upvote will count more than the rest of your 1000 posts so far. Yes, this [is broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295474/1983854).

Comment: Just wanted to throw my 2 cents in. I'm a very active user on the [tag:reactjs] tag, and have posted many answers. A few months back I was at ~95k people reached, then I posted an answer to a 2-year old question with ~100k views. The next day I found out that I had suddenly jumped up to ~195k people reached.

Comment: @fedorqui Oh my lord. My impact just jumped to 1.5mill.

Comment: Exactly, because answers with a score of >= 5 count towards the impact, no matter how many other answers are above that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So [Tim's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354671/has-the-impact-calculation-changed?noredirect=1#comment502268_354671) got me thinking... have there been any highly viewed questions I've posted in recently? Yes!

Here it is: [Python Numpy: how to count the number of true elements in a bool array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364674/python-numpy-how-to-count-the-number-of-true-elements-in-a-bool-array/45519545#45519545)

It seems the answer was upvoted recently (I wouldn't know since I made it a community wiki answer) and by virtue of being in the top 3 answers, my impact was recalculated to an increase by 72k, exactly the abnormal increase I noticed.

Problem solved.

Comment: The post detailing the calculation is here, btw: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here I assume it would be updated if it ever got changed.

Comment: now that's a strange calculation ;) last week you answered a 6 yrs old question and thus helped the 71k people who have never seen your answer!

Comment: Sounds similar to what is described in the first comment of @TylerH's linked post: _"Sanity Check: So I post the 73th answer to a question with a million views. A year later it gets to 5 votes. Does that mean I helped 1 million people? – Mysticial Dec 2 '14 at 18:57"_ Apparently, answering popular questions has big impact.

Comment: @jps Yep, it's imperfect for sure. I think the issue with splitting it out is that they don't track views by date, just an aggregate number. Otherwise they could award you just the views since you posted your answer, which would be much more accurate.

Comment: @TylerH that could be solved by storing in the Post table the pre-existing number of views of the question when creating the answer. Then doing a simple subtraction whenever you want.

Comment: @Cœur Sure, but on the scale of SO, I don't know if they want to bother with the cost of retrieving that per user even once a day. Plus it might mess with their normalization.

Comment: @Cœur ,TylerH from a technical standpoint it could be improved but I don't know if it's even worth the effort. What else does the number say than "so and so many people (or bots) requested the page which contained your post from the server." It doesn't even say that anyone ever scrolled down to read your answer. Anyway, I never thought much about that number, just came accross this topic today and found it funny and don't care much about it :)