# Is there an "impact history"?

Tags: discussion, people-reached

I *think* that my "impact" was way below 500 K when I checked last year. 
Now I just hit 1 million some days ago.

And in contrast to [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354671/has-the-impact-calculation-changed), I have no idea what could have got me several hundred thousands of reached users.

Simply confused here.

Comment: If you happen to have an answer on a popular question that due to votes becomes eligible for being taken into account in the impact calculation you can easily jump with big numbers in matters of minutes (give or take caching). Reasoning about it between *last year* and now is really not an option. And no, for us mortals impact is not kept (same for reputation). I don't even know if impact is kept in the internal SEDE database that is used by SE staff.  You can't reliably  know what caused that difference and I wouldn't be bothered by it either to be honest.

Comment: Maybe you can adapt some of the SEDE queries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50923511/578411 to find the posts that contribute most on your impact/people reached stat and work out from that lists which of your posts are to blame for that insane number ;)

Comment: @rene That link in your second comment goes to some delete answer on some unrelated SO question? C/P error?

Comment: Yes, C/P error, lack of coffee and too much multi-tasking: I meant to promote my own answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253596/158100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made a SEDE query myself for this purpose, but I couldn't make the *question is top 3 answer* work without triggering a timeout.

Anyway, you can easily use this to see your answers in top posts:

**[SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/864363/what-are-my-most-viewed-answers):**

```sql
--ToDo: Optimize calculation if your answer is top 3 or accepted, now triggers timeout

SELECT Top 100 IIF(questions.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##, 'Q', 'A') As QOrA, questions.Id As [Post Link], questions.ViewCount, IIF(questions.AcceptedAnswerId = answers.Id, 'True', 'False') As AnswerIsAccepted
From posts As questions
LEFT JOIN posts As answers ON (answers.ParentId = questions.Id And answers.OwnerUserID = ##UserId##)
WHERE questions.OwnerUserId = ##UserId## OR (answers.OwnerUserID = ##UserId##
-- Can't get this to work because of timeout, checks if your answer is top 3. 
-- AND (questions.AcceptedAnswerId = answers.Id OR answers.Id IN(SELECT Top 3 sAnswers.Id FROM posts sAnswers WHERE sAnswers.ParentId = questions.Id ORDER BY sAnswers.Score DESC))
)
ORDER BY questions.ViewCount DESC
```

Comment: this one works: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/864366/what-are-my-most-viewed-answers?UserId=578411 ( don't forget to add a where clause on posttypeid if you know you're dealing with answers only. That cuts the posts table into half at least.)

Comment: @rene Thanks, just rewrote that whole clause to a `NOT EXISTS` to escape the timeout, but I can use your change to make it even faster

Comment: Hmmm... I can't make it not timeout for less than 50% of cases, and my optimizations don't seem to do much (95% of the load is a clustered index scan). So either check yourself if the answer meets the criteria, or use rene's solution